# Finding a matrix for which a polynomial can be associated to a sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quaternions

I want to find (if it exists) a matrix $M$ with integer coefficients such that :

$a\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\,+ b\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\,+c\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\,+d\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=aM^{e_1}+bM^{e_2}+cM^{e_3}+dM^{e_4}$
where $e_i$ are integer exponents and $a,b,c,d$ positive integers.

Comment: you can check for yourself. Call the identity matrix $1$  and confirm that the other three square to $-1.$  Then the pairwise products, check for closure up to $\pm$ You want to be able to name $i,j,k$  such that $ij = k$  but $ji = -k$

Comment: The reason why I'm hesitant is that Wikipedia said that there should be 3 skew-symmetrical matrices (other than the identity) but in my case, there are only 2. But I'll check!

Comment: The d one is problematic, it doesn't square to -1 because it's symmetrical.

Comment: I can't, this is the matrices I want to work with

Comment: @DavidG. Your matrices definitely do not form a representation of the quaternions. Yours commute (i.e. each pair of matrices $A,B$ that can be generated satisfies $AB = BA$), but the quaternions do not

Comment: @BenGrossmann  finally checked that the "bc"  product and "cb"  are the "d" matrix. So, for what it is worth, this is an algebra  of some sort over the reals  and likely has a name

Comment: @WillJagy The closest to an official name this structure has, I think, is "the group ring of the Klein 4-group over $\Bbb C$".

Comment: @Ben  Thank you.

Comment: @WillJagy Sorry, that was sloppy. For one, all the matrices (besides the identity) being combined here satisfy $A^2 \neq I$. I think this is the group ring of $\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the analysis below is interesting, so I will leave it there. However, the fact that no such matrix $M$ can exist (even if we allow complex-number entries) can be quickly argued with an appeal to group theory.

Keeping the notation of the work below, I will denote
$$
I = \pmatrix{1 &0\\0&1}, \quad J = \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0},\\
M_0 = I \otimes I, \quad M_1 = I \otimes J, \quad M_2 = J \otimes I, \quad M_3 = J \otimes J,
$$

where $\otimes$ denotes a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). First of all, note that the matrices $M_0, M_1,M_2,M_3$ (with coefficients $a,b,c,d$ respectively) generate the following multiplicative group:
$$
G = \{J^p \otimes J^q : p,q \in \Bbb Z\} = \{\pm M_j: j = 0,1,2,3\} \cong \Bbb Z_{2}\times \Bbb Z_4.
$$
Suppose (for the purpose of contradiction) that $M$ were such that $M^{e_j} = M_j$ for $j = 0,1,2,3$. It would follow that $M$ is invertible and that $G$ must be a subgroup of the multiplicative group generated by $M$, $\langle M\rangle = \{M^p : p\in \Bbb Z\}$. This would mean that a cyclic group contains $G$, a non-cyclic group, as a subgroup. However, every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic, so this is impossible.

*Note:* Of course, the nature of $G$ can be found without building an explicit isomorphism since we can count and check the order of elements. That said, I found that building an isomorphism between $G$ and $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_4$ was a surprisingly counterintuitive exercise. Here is one isomorphism that can be constructed:

> $$\phi:G \to \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_4,\quad \phi(J^p \otimes J^q) = (p,q-p) \\ \text{ for } p = 1,2 \text{ and } q = 1,2,3,4 $$

The inverse is a bit more intuitive:

> $$\psi: \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_4 \to G, \quad \psi(p,q) = J^p \otimes J^{p+q} = (J \otimes J)^p (I\otimes J)^q.$$

---

The analysis of these matrices is made significantly easier with the help of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). In particular, if we define
$$
I = \pmatrix{1 &0\\0&1}, \quad J = \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0},
$$
then your linear combination can be written in the form
$$
a(I \otimes I) + b(I \otimes J) + c(J \otimes I) + d(J \otimes J).
$$
for convenience, I will denote the four matrices in the sum above as
$$
M_0 = I \otimes I, \quad M_1 = I \otimes J, \quad M_2 = J \otimes I, \quad M_3 = J \otimes J.
$$
Using the properties of the Kronecker product, it's easy to see that these matrices will commute, i.e. that $M_iM_k = M_kM_j$ for all $1 \leq j,k \leq 4$. Another convenient fact is that we can simulatenously diagonalize these matrices using a diagonalization of $J$. Let $U$ and $D$ denote the unitary and diagonal (respectively) matrices given below:
$$
U = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{-i&1\\1&-i}, \quad D = \pmatrix{i &0\\0& -i}.
$$
We find that $U^*JU = D$, where $U^*$ denotes the conjugate-tranpose of $U$ (which in this case is simply the conjugate of $U$). Accordingly, we find that $(U \otimes U)^*M_j (U \otimes U)$ is diagonal for all $j$. More specifically, if we define $P_j = (U \otimes U)^*M_j (U \otimes U)$, we find that
$$
P_0 = I \otimes I = M_0, \\
P_1 = I \otimes D = \operatorname{diag}(i,i,-i,-i),\\ 
P_2 = D \otimes I = \operatorname{diag}(i,-i,i,-i),\\ 
P_3 = D \otimes D = \operatorname{diag}(-1,1,1,-1),
$$
where $\operatorname{diag}(a,b,c,d)$ denotes the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $a,b,c,d$.

Now, if a matrix $M$ exists such that $M^{e_j} = M_j$ for each $j = 1,\dots,4$ and some integer exponents $e_j$, it would follow that the matrix $P = (U \otimes U)^*M(U \otimes U)$ is such that $P^{e_j} = P_j$ for each $j = 1,\dots,4$. If such a matrix $P$ exists, we can deduce the following:

- From the fact that $PP_j = P_jP$ for $j = 1,2$, we can deduce that $P$ must be a diagonal matrix.
- From the fact that $P^{e_0} = I$, we can deduce that each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $P$ (i.e. each diagonal entry of $P$) satisfies $\lambda^{e_0} = 1$ where $e_0$.
- From the fact that some power of $P$ has $i = \exp(\pi i/2)$ as an eigenvalue, we can deduce that $e_0$ is divisible by $4$. That is, $e_0 = 4n$ for some integer $n$.
- Because each diagonal entry of $P$ satisfies $\lambda^{4n} = 1$, we can deduce that each such entry has the form $\exp(2 \pi m_k i/e_0)$ for some integers $m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4$.

From there, we deduce that the exponents $e_1,e_2,e_3$ satisfy the follows equations:
$$
e_1 m_1 \equiv n \quad e_1m_2 \equiv n 
\quad e_1m_3 \equiv 3n \quad e_1m_4 \equiv 3n\\
e_2 m_1 \equiv n \quad e_2m_2 \equiv 3n 
\quad e_2m_3 \equiv n \quad e_2m_4 \equiv 3n\\
e_3 m_1 \equiv 2n \quad e_3m_2 \equiv 0 
\quad e_3m_3 \equiv 0 \quad e_3m_4 \equiv 2n,
$$
where $\equiv$ in the above denotes equality modulo $4n$.